# Как разделить строку с помощью find и erase

Tags: c++, find

Начал изучать совершенно новый для себя ЯП. Есть задача: разделить строку c помощью find и erase:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string name;
    cout << "Your nanme is: ";
    cin >> name;
    string firstname[1];
    string lastname[1];
}
```

В виду своей неопытности не могу решить такую легкую задачку, хоть и понимаю, что задачка решается с помощью массивов.  Просьба писать код с комментариями

Comment: Во-первых массивы вроде и не нужны. Если не поставлено условие разделить в массив. Во-вторых, что значит "разделить"? Как именно? Куда сложить части? Вводимая строка, кстати, пробелы может содержать или нет?

Comment: @Harry вообще по условию нужно получить две разных переменных типа string. Я пытался найти похожие вопросы, находил код, где люди решали с помощью массивов, без erase. 
По поводу пробелов - да, они должны быть. Именно с помощью пробелов мы реализуем метод find

Comment: Так, сформулируйте задачу, как вам ее задали, а не свою интерпретацию, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Harry "Пользователь вводит через пробел в консоль свои имя и фамилию. Получить 2 отдельные строки, где одна строка хранит имя, а другая фамилию. Использовать методы find() и erase()."

Comment: `string firstname, lastname; cin >> firstname >> lastname;` достаточно :) Скопируйте строку, вводимую `getline`, найдите пробел. В первой удалите все, начиная с пробела, во второй — все с начала до пробела включительно...